# What is the minimal non-zero value Math.random() can return in javascript

Tags: javascript, random

I know computers can't work with continuums. Math.random() javascript function returns a floating-point number between 0 (inclusively) and 1 (exclusively). I wonder what is the minimal non-zero number it can return. What "step" has this function?

Comment: I believe that in most implementations, the granularity is 2^53. So the answer would be 2^-53.

Comment: [The spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.8.2.14) says `using an implementation-dependent algorithm or strategy`, I'd guess the smallest result is what `1 / Number.MAX_VALUE` gives you (assuming non-zero result, e.g. `5.562684646268003e-309`)

Comment: The floating point value makes it interesting. For a typical C implementation, which returns an *integer*, `RAND_MAX` may be as low as 65535. While of course this can lead to lots of small decimals, ultimately the granularity is 1/65536, which is just about 4-and-bit decimals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard surely doesn't express this value, so it depends on the implementation (and exaggerating a bit on this point, probably even an implementation that aways returns 0.42 as result for `Math.random()` is still compliant with the specification).

The smallest positive number that can be represented by a 64-bit normalized floating point number in IEEE754 format is 2<sup>−1022</sup>, i.e. 2.2250738585072014 × 10<sup>−308</sup>.

However the floating point representation uses a varying resolution, depending on the magnitude.

For numbers close to 1 the resolution is 2<sup>-53</sup>. Probably (just **probably**) many implementations pick a random integer number `n` between 0 and 2<sup>53</sup>-1 and use as result `n/9007199254740992`.

Comment: That number looks like this in decimal: 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000022250738585072014. It's pretty small.

Comment: What I find amazing is that if you pass that decimal string to a string to float conversion the result is correct (even if of course it's one of the test cases they use).

Answer (score 1):

It's almost certainly not from just picking any random float.

That would not accurately represent the step of the random function, because it would not even be close to uniform distribution. Let's say you got that 2<sup>-1022</sup> "step" (smallest non-zero value that fits in a float), plus 0.25 as a random value. Well, that would be rounded to 0.25 because floats can't represent that accuracy. So you've have a whole swathe of "values" that are all equal to 0.25 due to rounding. This is not even remotely uniform.

I would say it's more likely that a float is generated with the exponent set to 0 with random bits for the mantissa, which would result in randomness of step 2<sup>-51</sup> (I think XD) between 1 (included) and 2 (not included), from which you can then just subtract 1. In this case, the step would be the size of the mantissa.

Comment: On which part you don't agree? The one in which I'm saying the standard doesn't cover this point or the part in which I'm stating what is the smallest number that can be represented by a double-precision number?

Comment: @6502 Both parts are correct, but the second one isn't really relevant and kind of misleading in this context because it kind of suggests you're claiming that to be the step of the random function. At least, that's how I interpreted it XD

Comment: Point taken anyway. Edited the answer to what is (probably) what an implementation can do to extract uniform random numbers.

Comment: "Picking random bits" ... surely the floating point storage format would bias the outcome then? (Must find reference. I *know* this'll lead to a logarithmic spread, rather than linear.)

Comment: @Jongware: you can get uniform spread by fixing exponent and randomly choosing the 52 mantissa bits. Later you can normalize the representation.

Answer (score 0):

[ECMA provides no guidelines for the precision of randomness](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.8.2.14):

> Returns a Number value with positive sign, greater than or equal to 0 but less than 1, chosen randomly or pseudo randomly with approximately uniform distribution over that range, using an implementation-dependent algorithm or strategy. This function takes no arguments.

`Math.random()` returns a `double` between 0 and 1. We can ignore the exponent, and the sign, and we're left with 53 usable bits. This means that the minimum possible step between numbers in a perfect world is **`1/2^53 == 0.00000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125`**.

However, the prevailing JavaScript implementations provide *different* levels of randomness:

- V8 (Chrome, chromium, node.js): 32 bits ([src](https://github.com/v8/v8-git-mirror/blob/bd21d72d507625e5caf70f31ee11c8c21ead1651/src/math.js))
- JavaScriptCore (Safari) 32 bits ([src](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=113635))
- SpiderMonkey (Firefox): 53 bits ([src](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=464071))
- Internet Explorer 53 bits

While some environments will give you more, the least common denominator in the wild is *32 bits*. Even on a server, your node.js app only gets 32 bits.

The minimum precision you can *depend* on if you want your application to run correctly everywhere is **`1/2^32 == 0.00000000023283064365386962890625`**.

Comment: I firmly believe that assuming every user is using one implementation is lazy and generally bad advice. Whether you like it or not, other browsers **are** used and should be accounted for.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what the spec says, but a quick test in the console of Chrome, Firefox, and IE11 shows that the precision never goes beyond 20 decimal places.

Test it yourself:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) console.log(Math.random());
```

Or to see the smallest number after a large number of iterations:

```
var smallest = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) smallest = Math.min(smallest, Math.random());
```

Comment: I'm not super familiar with javascript, but what are the odds that `console.log` only writes 20 decimal places by default?

Comment: This kind of test is a **really bad** way to determine minimum values. There is an unimaginably large amount of numbers between 1.0 and 10^(-20) so the chances that `random()` picks a number less than 10^(-20) is practically zero - regardless of how many iterations you pick for your loop. So even if it is possible you would never see `random()` generate a number smaller than 10^(-20) simply because it is so insanely unlikely.

Comment: From a purely mathematical perspective you would need at least 10^20 iterations to even have a shot at getting a value less than 10^(-20). And if we forget for a moment how inefficient doing something like this is you can still never be sure that your answer is correct. Because no matter how many iterations you run, there is always the possibility that you simply were unlucky and the lowest possible number still hasn't been returned. So to go back to my original statement, really a bad way to determine something like this.

Comment: @MooingDuck: The console outputs full precision using E notation, so that is not a limiting factor.

Comment: @XaverKapeller: I wasn't suggesting you could get the smallest number with my approach. I said you could get the smallest number "after a large number of iterations." My point was that every number in a set of 1,000,000 fell within a few digits of 20 decimal places of precision, so that is likely the range you can expect from calls to Math.random().

Comment: Well I got that, my point is that that is useless information. Imagine 100,000 people use your website for a year. Even if there is only one call to `random()` per page visit then you are going to have **a lot** more calls than 1,000,000 in that year. You cannot make assumptions like that in a production environment.

Comment: @XaverKapeller 64 bit granularity would result in a minimum of 5.4210109e-20, which is pretty darn close to Bradon's measurements.  I bet that's not a coincidence.